# Curly braces marked as syntax error in Vim

Tags: c, vim

I am using vim 8.1 and while writing C code, I am noticing all my curly braces are using red background with white foreground.  After some digging, I found this setting in my theme:
`call s:hi('Error',           { 'fg': s:white, 'bg': s:red })`
I have confirmed this is where the color is coming from, by modifying the color here.

Since this is noted as a syntax error and i have `syntax on` in my vimrc I am confused why my curly braces are showing as a syntax error.  This happens even in very simple code such as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused why this is showing as an error.  This is happening if I put the opening curly brace at the end of the main definition or after it.  If i run `clist` vim tells me there are no errors.  vimrc is viewable at: https://pastebin.com/LukL8MBg

EDIT 1:
On further digging, the issue appears to be with the colortheme I am using.  There is a file that contains this for syntax:

```
syn keyword cDeclarationOverwrite var const type 
syn match cBraces       "[{}\[\]]"
syn match cParens       "[()]"
syn match cOpSymbols    "=\{1,2}\|!=\|<\|>\|>=\|<=\|++\|+=\|--\|-="
syn match cEndColons    "[,]"
syn match cLogicSymbols "\(&&\)\|\(||\)\|\(!\)"
```

EDIT 2:
On recommendation of user @filbranden i ran `:scriptnames` and see the following:

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
 10: ~/.vim/plugins/purify/vim/colors/purify.vim
 11: ~/.vim/plugins/purify/vim/autoload/purify.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/dist/ft.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/c.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent/c.vim
 27: ~/.vim/plugins/purify/vim/syntax/c.vim
 28: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/c.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

From the looks of things here, c.vim from the purify plugin is loaded before vim's syntax/c.vim which is being loaded last.

output of `:set rtp?` shows:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/plugins/purify/vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim81,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

Comment: What if you put the `{` at the end of the previous line? It might be a style warning.

Comment: No same thing no matter where i place the braces.

Comment: would you mind sharing your vimrc file?

Comment: @NicolasMartinez vimrc is at https://pastebin.com/LukL8MBg

Comment: What does the command `:hi cBraces` tell you?

Comment: I get interesting colour effects when there's a mismatched something or other elsewhere in my code.  For example, if there's a mistake in a function declaration before `main()`, you might see odd colouring.  However, if you're seeing it on the code you show (and there is no other code in the file) then there's probably something astray with the bits and pieces you're using in your vimrc set up — and good luck debugging it.

Comment: @filbranden cBraces        xxx ctermfg=75 guifg=#5FAFFF

Comment: @johca Yeah that looks sane... Just to make absolutely sure... If you query `:set ft?` do you see `filetype=c` or something else? Making sure you're getting the right filetype detection here...

Comment: @filbranden Yes, filetype is detected correctly.  I think there is something with the theme i am using.  If i remove that and use a different theme, things are ok.  I don't know enough about how the custom themes are built yet to debug it entirely.

Comment: @johca Yeah that particular theme is adding extra syntax for C, which is what you're seeing there with the match for `cBraces`, but it seems that part is right and you're actually getting a group mapping to Error on the braces...

Comment: Can I suggest that you install plug-in [scriptease.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) and then use the `zS` command from that plug-in to inspect the active highlight groups under the cursor while you're on a brace? That might give a better hint of what is going on...

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for this.  I ran this, and got ```cErrInParen cBadBlock cParen```

Comment: I can reproduce that with `int main(int argc, char **argv { return 0; }`, note the missing `)`... Are you sure you don't have any other syntax errors like that in your C source file?

Comment: @filbranden positive.  The whole source file is as in my original question.  I just got sick of looking at the highlighted curly braces.  So i tried with no code at all just a main decleration and still err.

Comment: @johca Puzzling! Try this, run this command to save the syntax configuration to a buffer `:put =execute('syntax')`. Do that from the small sample C source file. Save that somewhere and poste a paste to it? I'd be curious to see if there's anything else weird with your syntax rules...

Comment: @filbranden here is the output from that command: https://pastebin.com/eQEszDEn

Comment: I think I have a clue... It might be an ordering issue between the native C syntax and that of purify... If you inspect the syntax of the parentheses, does either or both show as `cParens` ? (Note the difference from `cParen` singular...)

Comment: @filbranden I do not find any reference in the theme source to 'cParen'.  The only reference to the cParens definition I could find is for color located in https://github.com/kyoz/purify/blob/master/vim/colors/purify.vim

Comment: `cParen` exists and it's from the Vim native support for C syntax. You already found it with your `zS` on the curly braces... What I meant was use `zS` on the parens on the `int main` line to see if they show up as `cParen` or `cParens`.

Comment: You might also want to include: output of `:set rtp?` and also output of `:scriptnames`. Preferrably in a fresh Vim, just opening that simple C file. (I'm trying to see which `c.vim` is loaded first, the one from Purify or the one from Vim runtimes. I think Vim runtimes should be first, but in your case it seems the Purify one is loading first...)

Comment: BTW, please edit the post to include that information. It probably doesn't fit in the comments...

Comment: @filbranden Oh sorry for the misunderstanding.  Yes, when I run ```zS``` on the red curly brace it shows as ```cErrInParen cBadBlock cParen```, when I run ```zS``` on the parentheses it shows ```cParens cParen```

Comment: @filbranden will update the original question with the info you asked for.  Assuming that ```:scriptnames``` output in the order of loading, you are correct i see ```c.vim``` loaded before ```/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/c.vim```

Comment: Actually, it seems this order is correct... I still don't know exactly what's wrong here. I might have a workaround for you though: add `let g:c_no_curly_error = 1` to your vimrc file... Can you check whether that works for you? I'll try to reproduce this locally tomorrow, get this colorscheme and see if I get the same trouble, debug this some more... Very interesting problem!

Comment: @filbranden setting that removed the error on the opening curl braces, but still shows an error on the closing curl brace.  Appreciate the help if your able to understand where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems to me that this is a bug in the syntax rules set by the `kyoz/purify` plugin, in particular regarding the ordering of the rules in relation to the rules from the Vim runtimes.

When the a plugin manager added a plugin, it will add that plugin's directory to `'runtimepath'`, and it will add it *before* the Vim runtime directory. This is done so that plugins can override files shipped in the Vim runtimes, by having a chance to run earlier.

In particular, this means that the syntax rules in the `kyoz/purity` plugin will be added *before* the ones from the Vim runtimes when a file of type C is loaded.

Now, it turns out that this triggers a conflict in how the rules interact with each other.

Let's for example examine the interaction between `cParen` (from Vim runtimes) and `cParens` (from `kyoz/purify`.) For simplicity, let's assume we're using `let g:c_no_curly_error = 1`, just so we don't have to discuss having two `end=` groups, but the same rationale also applies for the case where that global variable is unset.

With the current ordering, we end up with [`cParens` from `kyoz/purify`](https://github.com/kyoz/purify/blob/09fd532c4c0d3a87ec3a30c5bc2ed26a03fbc7a4/vim/syntax/c.vim#L5) coming before [`cParen` from the Vim runtime](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/c.vim#L140):

```
" From kyoz/purify:
syn match cParens       "[()]"
" From Vim runtime:
syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' contains=ALLBUT,...
```

Now the first thing about syntax rules is that the rule that comes *after* wins. So when Vim encounters `(`, which could match both (either `cParens` which matches either, or `cParen`'s `start` which matches `(` exactly), it will pick `cParen` (from Vim runtime), since that comes later.

That's all fine... But then why do we have a problem at the `)`?

Since `cParen` is a "region", Vim will keep going trying to match the `end` part of it. While doing so, it will also try to match the groups in `contains`. But here, `contains` starts with `ALLBUT`, which means it will try to match every group *except* the ones in the explicit list. Which means it will *also* match `cParens` inside that group.

Now, this is what causes the problem, because if `cParens` is matching the `)`, then that means the `)` will not be recognized as the end of `cParen`. This is actually described under [`:help :syn-keepend`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-keepend):

> By default, a contained match can obscure a match for the end pattern. This is useful for nesting.  For example, a region that starts with `{` and ends with `}`, can contain another region.  An encountered `}` will then end the contained region, but not the outer region.
>
> If you don't want this, the `keepend` argument will make the matching of an end pattern of the outer region also end any contained item. This makes it impossible to nest the same region, but allows for contained items to highlight parts of the end pattern, without causing that to skip the match with the end pattern.

So if we had `keepend` on the region rule from Vim runtime, this would actually end the `cParen` rule, which would not cause the issue. But since that's not the case, having `cParens` match the `)` means the `cParen` will run off until the end of the file, which will cause the curly braces to trigger errors (since in C they're not allowed inside parentheses.)

If we *did* have `keepend`, the situation would be slightly better in that the `cParen` would see its end. But it would still not be ideal, since `kyov/purify`'s `cParens` would only match the `)` and would not really match the `(`. (You would need something like `matchgroup` to also match the delimiters, but that's another topic.)

So that should explain why this happens.

---

So what can we do about it?

It seems to me that loading the rules in the opposite order would be better here.

```
" From Vim runtime:
syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' contains=ALLBUT,...
" From kyoz/purify:
syn match cParens       "[()]"
```

Since, when there are multiple matches, Vim will use the rule that comes *last*, this will always only trigger `cParens` for a `(`, so we don't have the problem with the runaway group. `)` will only match `cParens` as well (in that case that's not a conflict with `cParen` anymore, since that would only match the end of a group.)

This will make the rules from `kyov/purify` work as expected.

But it does have a side-effect! That the `cParen` rule from Vim runtimes will be completely shadowed by that plugin. (And also similar rules that match on the same characters, for example, `cBlock`.

Is that a problem? Maybe. It seems most of those rules are marked `transparent` (they don't affect highlighting directly) and are mostly used to flag situations such as marking unbalanced or unmatched braces, flagging them as Error (similar to what you were seeing, but for actual syntax problems.)

If you think the use case from `kyov/purify` (which is to color the braces) is preferrable to the one in the Vim runtimes, then you might be fine with shadowing the rules in the Vim runtimes.

This can be accomplished by moving the syntax rules to under an `after/` subdirectory. Plugin managers will recognize an `after/` directory in a plugin, and they will add it *after* the Vim runtimes. That's the established mechanism to allow plugins to decide whether they want their rules to come before the ones from Vim runtimes (which is the most common case), or come later.

Since I believe this is a bug in `kyov/purify`, I opened [a pull request](https://github.com/kyoz/purify/pull/2) that moves the rules for C and C++ to an `after/` directory. Testing it locally, it seemed to fix the issue you reported above, without really introducing any adverse issues. (Pull request was promptly merged, so it seems the author agreed with this being a bug there.)

Comment: Nice work on this @filbranden and thank you for the detailed explanation.  I learned a lot about troubleshooting plugins.  I see your PR has already been merged and is behaving as expected on my system now.  Thank you !

Comment: Now I’m wondering if packages go after or before the vim runtime i’ve never bothered to notice

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Same here, I didn't really know it until this question. Unfortunately the docs are not explicit on this. I found plugins and packages are put exactly *around* Vim runtime, with the root coming before it and the `after/` subdir coming after it. Which makes sense, since you'd want the opportunity to override something from runtime, so this ordering makes sense...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble *"Now I'm wondering if packages go after or before the vim runtime"*. I asked a [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24473/18609) about the exact rules in Vi & Vim SE. Hoping we'll get this well documented now. Cheers!