# C/C++ error-highlighting in vim on closing braces/parens

Tags: c, vim

Sometimes I will get incorrect error-highlighting on a closing parenthesis or brace. Here is a good example using a function pointer:

[image]
Now, unless I have a syntax error that I'm not seeing (please point it out if so!), how would I get rid of this formatting? Is there a particular setting or perhaps syntax file where this can be fixed?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this myself, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60983778/7431860) seems a bit similar and suggests it might have something to do with themes. FWIW though I've been a vim user for going on 8 years and never even heard of themes before now, so take that with a grain of salt!

Comment: Which color scheme are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Try with `$ vim -Nu NONE filename +syntax\ on`.